# How to get current frame number using ffmpeg c++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, frame, decode

Usually, I use the below code to get the current frame number when decoding a video.

```
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
      // Decode video frame
      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

      // Did we get a video frame?
      if(frameFinished) {
    int currentFrameNumber = pFrame->coded_picture_number; 
    }
    /* Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame*/
    av_free_packet(&packet);
  }
```

Then, when I implemented seeking feature, I add av_seek_frame to seek to a desired position like this:

```
if(av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx, -1, seekTarget, 0 )<0){
         LOG("log","error when seeking");
}
while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
          // Decode video frame
          avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

          // Did we get a video frame?
          if(frameFinished) {
        int currentFrameNumber = pFrame->coded_picture_number; 
        }
        /* Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame*/
        av_free_packet(&packet);
 }
```

This is when the problem arises. pFrame->coded_picture_number returns incorrect value. 
My question is how I cam get the current frame given I have a decoded frame pFrame ?

Comment: Is coded_picture_number what you want? It is in decode order, not display order... The AVFrame structure has a member display_picture_number which is the actual frame #.

Comment: coded_picture_number is correct value if I don't use av_seek_frame for seeking.

Comment: display_picture_number is often zero and is unreliable.